# Almacenar 'form' en una variable - Meteor

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

Estoy intentado almacenar una entrada por telcado o `input` en una variable, pero cuando intento intento imprimirla me devuelve vacío.

Se trata de un login simple.

Tengo un archivo llamado login.js, en que el que establezco el `from` de la siguiente manera:

```
Template.login.events({
'submit form': function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    Meteor.loginWithPassword(**aux =** event.target.usuario.value, event.target.clave.value, function(err){
```

En cuanto al archivo html, el código que presenta es el siguiente:

```
div class="modal-body">
      <form class="form col-md-12 center-block">
        <div class="form-group">
         <input name="usuario" type="text" id="inputEmail" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Usuario" required autofocus>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
         <input name="clave" type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Contraseña" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
         <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Ingresar</button>
         <br>
         <!--Es posible que sea necesario,destinar un link, para ayudar al usuario en el caso de que no pueda acceder-->
         <span><a id="ayuda" href="#">¿Necesitas ayuda?</a></span>
        </div>
      </form>
  </div>
```

Al intentar imprimir el valor de dicha variable desde otro `template` (`{{aux}}`), a través del archivo html ,no imprime ningún valor. El valor que intento almacenar e imprimir en otro `template` es el nombre del usuario,

He intentado este proceso importando y exportando la variable de varias formas, pero nunca consigo imprimir el valor. La verdad, no tengo muy claro como hacerlo (soy nuevo en la programación web, y Meteor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 Template.tutemplate.helpers({
 currentUser: function() {
  return Meteor.userId();
 }
})
```

Comment: Para imprimir el username, ¿cómo sería?

Comment: return Meteor.user().username;